# The possessive case of multiple nouns

Tags: possessives, coordination

Which sentence is the most natural?

1. I visited Tom and Mary's school.
2. I visited Tom's and Mary's school.
3. I visited the school of Tom and Mary.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question, another alternative is to paraphrase, perhaps something like *the school Tom and Mary go to* or *the school Tom and Mary run*, depending on the specific relationship you're trying to express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further context, I consider that Tom & Mary are the ***students***.

So,

if the two persons belong to the ***same*** school, I think the natural way is

> I visited Tom and Mary's school

If both are in different schools, it can be

> I visited Tom's and Mary's **schools** *(note the plural)*

The same thing can be applied to the third instance.